# Hay alguna diferencia entre T00 y T02

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-format

Estoy sustituyendo momento por date-fns en el proyecto del trabajo. Es mi primera tarea, además de ser mi primera experiencia como front.

El caso es que me han dejado sólo, yupi jejjee y estaba cambiando una función de moment
`moment(el).toISOString(true)`

Cuando imprimo lo que hacela función de momento (me he creado un entorno para ir haciendo pruebas) me devuelve esto.

**Moment test = 2021-07-28T00:00:00.000+02:00**

Mi duda es si lo que me devuelve date-fns estaría correcto en comparación a moment a las pequeñas diferencias, afectarían.

**Date fns tes= 2021-07-28T02:00:00+02:00**

Un un resultado aparece T00 en el otro T02, no quiero cambiar nada sin estar seguro voy bien, no vaya a ser que la pifie.